# Given a standard Brownian motion $W_t$, (i) what are the distributions of $|W_t|$ and $tW_t$? (ii) Are they martingales?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, martingales

For (i), I believe I am correct in saying that $|W_t|$ is a folded normal distribution with mean $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}t$ and variance $t$, and $tW_t$ is distributed normally with $\mathbb{E}(tW_t)=0, \text{Var}(tW_t)=t^3$?

For (ii) I'm not confident since I have only ever covered discrete-time martingales but using an analogous argument to the discrete case where we check if $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|X_0,...,X_n)=X_n$, I am going to hazard a guess that the first one is a martingale, the second isn't?

Comment: A martingale must be at the least a process with constant mean (Law of iterated expectation). Now, is $|W_t|$ a process with constant mean? Also, if you've covered only discrete time martingales then I suggest you read up the definition of continuous time martingales before attempting this question, since an answer for the second may make no sense. It is also unclear that you are aware of the notion of $\sigma$-algebras and conditional expectation, please explain your background?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг no $|W_t|$ doesn't have constant mean, so I'm guessing I've got the two the wrong way round?

Comment: It is true that you have the first one wrong for the reason I specified (I will make myself absolutely sure the second one is , and then reply to you. My guess is that it is a martingale for now). Kindly address my other question, so I can answer this in the right way (Without involving unknown terminology).

Comment: I understand conditional expectation, but I have not yet encountered $\sigma$-algebras and I have only encountered the basics of discrete-time Martingales i.e. the basic definition that $X_n$ has finite mean and $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|X_0,...,X_n)=X_n$ and some basic properties

Comment: You must then be asked to prove that $tW_t$ is a *discrete-time* martingale, right? That would basically involve showing that $\mathbb E[(t+1)W_{t+1}| W_1,2W_2,...tW_{t}] = tW_{t}$, right? (And integrability, but that you've done) Note that this is in fact a continuous time martingale, but for that you require the sigma-algebra definition of conditional expectation (and hence martingale) which you don't have.